# Scraping a table with Puppeteer, how can I format each td element as an object property?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I want to create an object from an HTML table, with each td innerText as object properties. The issue is I'm only able to store the entire text inside one property, not separate ones.

```
puppeteer.launch().then(async function(browser) {
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population');


const countriesData = await page.$$eval('table tr ', countries => {
    return countries.map(country => {
        return {country: country.innerText};
    })
})

console.log(countriesData)

await browser.close();})
```

It logs each country like this:

```
{country: '1\t China[b]\t1,403,148,200\t18.0%\t18 Jun 2020\tNational population clock[3]'},
```

But want this:

```
{id, name, population, percentage,},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve the problem with a simple **for loop**.

1.) Define an object structure, in my example I used a JavaScript class `CountryItem`, you can use anything else of course that you prefer. Then create an empty array (`countries`) where we can collect all instances of the countries.

2.) Get the exact number of table rows (`countriesLength` in the example, you will need to add + 1 to its value to reach the last item as well).

3.) Write a for loop that iterates over all `<tr>`-s.

4.) The data from the `<td>`-s can be retrieved with their exact selectors where:

- `tr:nth-child(${ **number of row** })` and
- `td:nth-child(${ **1 = Rank; 2 = Name; 3 = Country name; 4 = Population etc.** })`.

5.) With each iteration create a new `CountryItem` with the actual scraped strings and push it to the main object (the empty array we've defined at the beginning).

**Example code:**

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

puppeteer.launch().then(async function (browser) {
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population')

  const countries = []
  class CountryItem {
    constructor(id, name, population, percentage, date, source) {
      this.id = id
      this.name = name
      this.population = population
      this.percentage = percentage
      this.date = date
      this.source = source
    }
  }
  const tableSelector = '#mw-content-text > div > table > tbody'
  const countriesLength = await page.$$eval(`${tableSelector} > tr`, el => el.length)

  // iterate over tr:nth-child(${i}) on all rows
  for (let i = 1; i < countriesLength + 1; i++) {
    const id = i
    const name = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, await page.$(`${tableSelector} > tr:nth-child(${i}) > td:nth-child(2)`))
    const population = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, await page.$(`${tableSelector} > tr:nth-child(${i}) > td:nth-child(3)`))
    const percentage = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, await page.$(`${tableSelector} > tr:nth-child(${i}) > td:nth-child(4)`))
    const date = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, await page.$(`${tableSelector} > tr:nth-child(${i}) > td:nth-child(5)`))
    const source = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, await page.$(`${tableSelector} > tr:nth-child(${i}) > td:nth-child(6)`))

    const actualCountryItem = new CountryItem(id, name, population, percentage, date, source)
    countries.push(actualCountryItem)
  }
  console.log(countries)

  await browser.close()
})
```

**Output example:**

```
...
  CountryItem {
    id: 99,
    name: ' Austria',
    population: '8,902,600',
    percentage: '0.114%',
    date: '1 Jan 2020',
    source: 'Quarterly provisional figure[91]'
  },
  CountryItem {
    id: 100,
    name: ' Switzerland',
    population: '8,603,899',
    percentage: '0.110%',
    date: '31 Dec 2019',
    source: 'National provisional figure[92]'
  },
  ...
]
```